# why csv writer put comma after each letter in python

Tags: python

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

links = []
titles = []

def scraper():
    for page in range(1, 3):
        url = 'https://ww1.gogoanime2.org/animelist'
        req = requests.get(url + '/' + str("all") + '/' + str(page))
        soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
        anime_list = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'anime_list_body'})
        animes = anime_list.findAll('a', href=True)

        for anime in animes:
            global links
            global titles
            links.append(anime['href'])
            titles.append(anime.text)

            with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                writer.writerows(titles)


scraper()
```

Comment: Each element of `titles` (the rows you are writing to the csv file) is a string, but csv expects it to be a sequence of values that it should join with commas.

Comment: Because `writer.writerowS` wants multiple rows of data in a list of lists - kindof like `[ ["header1","header2"], ["row1_col1","row2_col2"], ["row2_col1","row2_col2"],  ... ]`

Comment: try `titles.append([anime.text])` to create a csv with 1 column - each row having one anime.text as data  - and dont write inside the FOR loop - that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.writerows` to `.writerow`

Let us know how you get on!